# Python ServiceNow Semaphore Timeout Error

Tags: python, servicenow

Trying to connect to a ServiceNow instance and pull information from the tables.  I am using the aiosnow module.  Here is the  code:

```
import asyncio
import getpass

import aiosnow
from aiosnow.models.table.declared import IncidentModel as Incident

# Get user input
instanceSN = input("Enter the instance name:  ")
usernameSN = input("Enter your ServiceNow username:  ")
passwordSN = getpass.getpass()

async def main():
    client = aiosnow.Client(instanceSN, basic_auth=(usernameSN,passwordSN))

    async with Incident(client, table_name="incident") as inc:
        query = aiosnow.select(
            Incident.assigned_to.starts_with(<insert username>)
        ).order_asc(Incident.priority)

        for response in await inc.get(query, limit=5):
            print("Attaching [readme.txt] to {number} ({sys_id})".format(**response))
            await inc.upload_file(response["sys_id"], path="./readme.txt")

asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run this I get the following error message:
aiosnow.exceptions.ClientConnectionError: Cannot connect to host servicenow.example.com:443 ssl:default [The semaphore timeout period has expired]